Как функцией переключить экран Kivy
Пишу игру. В поле TextInput в LowGame игрок должен ввести ответ на пример, ответ сравнивается с правильным и должно произойти две вещи:
Либо ответ правильный и нас кидает в WinAndLeave, либо ответ неправильный и нас кидает в GameOver. Я не очень понимаю как мне реализовать функцию этого сравнения, чтоб на выходе получать необходимое. Прикладываю свои APP.py и MyApp.kv файлы:

APP.py


from random import randint

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import *
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import *
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.settings import *
from kivy.core.window import *
from kivy.config import *
from kivy.uix.widget import *
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import *
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty

Window.fullscreen = "auto"

A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
B = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
a = randint(0, 9)
b = randint(0, 9)
if A[a] < B[b]:
    symb = '+'
else:
    symb = '-'
if symb == '+':
    answer = A[a] + B[b]
else:
    answer = A[a] - B[b]

class MyApp(Widget):
    pass


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class DifficultyWindow(Screen):
    pass


class GameOver(Screen):
    pass


class LowGame(Screen):
    def algebraic(self):
        global A
        global B
        global a
        global b
        global symb
        return str(A[a]) + symb + str(B[b])
    def check_answ(self):
        global answer
        text_input = ObjectProperty()
        if self.text_input.text == answer:
            return (ЧТО ЗАСУНУТЬ СЮДА)
        else:
            return (ЧТО ЗАСУНУТЬ СЮДА)

class NormalGame(Screen):
    pass


class WinAndLeave(Screen):
    pass


class HardGame(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("MyApp.kv")


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()



MyApp.kv

WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    DifficultyWindow:
    LowGame:
    NormalGame:
    HardGame:
    GameOver:
    WinAndLeave:

    
<MainWindow>:
    name: "Main"
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'Background.jpg'
    Button:
        id: Play
        text: "Играть"
        color: "red"
        font_size: self.height/2
        on_release: app.root.current = "Difficulty"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint: (0.05, 0.05)
    Button:
        text: "Выход"
        color: "black"
        font_size: self.height/2
        on_release: app.stop()
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.1}
        size_hint: (0.05, 0.05)

<DifficultyWindow>:
    name: "Difficulty"
    Button:
        color: "red"
        font_size: self.height/2
        text: "Назад"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Main"
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.05,'y': 0.9}
        size_hint: (0.05, 0.05)
    Button:
        text: "Лёгкий"
        color: "green"
        font_size: self.height/2
        on_release: app.root.current = "Low"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.6}
        size_hint: (0.05, 0.05)
    Button:
        text: "Нормальный"
        color: "blue"
        font_size: self.height/2
        on_release: app.root.current = "Normal"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint: (0.08, 0.05)
    Button:
        text: "Сложный"
        color: "red"
        font_size: self.height/2
        on_release: app.root.current = "Win"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.4}
        size_hint: (0.06, 0.05)

<LowGame>
    name: "Low"
    text_input: text_input
    Label:
        text: root.algebraic()
        size_hint: 1, 1.4
        font_size: 26
        halign: 'center'
    TextInput:
        id: text_input
        multiline: False
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.4}
    Button:
        text: 'Ответить'
        font_size: self.height/2
        on_release: root.check_answ(self)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.3}
        size_hint: (0.06, 0.05)
<NormalGame>
    name: "Normal"
    Label:
        text: "Приложение на стадии разработки, сложность недоступна"
        text_size: (400, 400)
        font_size: 26
        halign: 'center'
    Button:
        color: "red"
        font_size: self.height/2
        text: "Назад"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Main"
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.05,'y': 0.9}
        size_hint: (0.05, 0.05)
<HardGame>
    name: "Hard"
    Label:
        text: "Приложение на стадии разработки, сложность недоступна"
        text_size: (400, 400)
        font_size: 26
        halign: 'center'
    Button:
        color: "red"
        font_size: self.height/2
        text: "Назад"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Main"
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.05,'y': 0.9}
        size_hint: (0.05, 0.05)
<GameOver>:
    name: "Defeat"
    Label:
        text: "Вы проиграли, сожалею. Вернитесь на главный экран"
        text_size: (400, 400)
        font_size: 26
        halign: 'center'
    Button:
        color: "red"
        font_size: self.height/2
        text: "Назад"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Main"
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.05,'y': 0.9}
        size_hint: (0.05, 0.05)
<WinAndLeave>:
    name: "Win"
    Label:
        text: "Поздравляю, вы ответили правильно. Вернитесь на главный экран"
        text_size: (400, 400)
        font_size: 26
        halign: 'center'
    Button:
        color: "red"
        font_size: self.height/2
        text: "Назад"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Main"
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.05,'y': 0.9}
        size_hint: (0.05, 0.05)```


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!
Формат сайта подразумевает общение в виде вопросов и ответов на них и, хотя программисты любят поговорить о чем угодно, всё-таки некоторые вопросы не приветствуются ===>
...Поиск ошибок в коде. Прежде чем спрашивать «почему у меня не работает вот этот (простыня из тысячи строк) код?» постарайтесь сами локализовать проблему, выделить минимальный фрагмент кода, на котором, как вы считаете возникает проблема. Прочитайте о том, как создать минимальный, но самодостаточный пример =>
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

и еще справку как задать хороший вопрос ===> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

sm = ScreenManager()

for i in range(4):
    screen = Screen(name='Title %d' % i)
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = 'Title 2'

Проверите, если будет работать.

Здесь все очень просто, вам просто нужно переключить на другой экран, и я бы объявил класс WindowManager раньше, насколько я понял у вас все экраны подключены и выбран LowGame
def check_answ(self):
    global answer
    text_input = ObjectProperty()
    if self.text_input.text == answer:
        WindowManager.current="Win" 
    else:
        WindowManager.current="Defeat" 

Проверьте, работает или нет
